# why lowercaseString of NSString is not released after the original NSString object is released?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Please check the following code:

```
CFUUIDRef uuid=CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
NSString *strUuid=(NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault,uuid);
NSString *lowerUuid=[strUuid lowercaseString];
NSLog(@"strUuid retainCount:%tu",[strUuid retainCount]);
CFRelease(strUuid);
CFRelease(uuid);
NSLog(@"lowerUuid retainCount:%tu",[lowerUuid retainCount]);
NSLog(@"lowerUuid:%@",lowerUuid);
```

run this code in a non-arc project, the output will be:

```
strUuid retainCount:1
lowerUuid retainCount:1
lowerUuid:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

lowercaseString is a property of NSString, its definition is:

```
@property (readonly, copy) NSString *lowercaseString;
```

so it's reasonable to infer that if the original NSString object is released, lowercaseString property will be released in NSString's dealloc method.
But why in the code above, lowerUuid is still there even after the original strUuid is released?

Comment: I don't think that's a reasonable inference.  The `copy` attribute probably means that the returned value is a copy of the original string, complete with it's own retain count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, standard disclaimer: Don't look `-retainCount`. It has many caveats to its use and can't really be trusted for anything useful.

That said: Your inference does not describe what's happening. When you ask `strUuid` for a `-lowercaseString`, you're not getting some sort of "child" object. The resulting lowercased string is a completely independent object, with its own internal retain count. (It's possible that the original string does retain its own reference to the lowercased string, but that's not your concern.)

In your code snippet, under standard memory management conventions, what is happening in general terms is that the statement `[strUuid lowercaseString]` returns an "autoreleased" object. So that even if the original string is released, the string that was returned to you remains valid either: (a) *at least* until the autorelease pool is cleaned up or (b) after its last actual access, depending on ARC status on the project.

Comment: Good answer. To expand a bit: just because something is declared as a `@property` doesn't mean it's some kind of subordinate object. A readonly property is just a getter method that can return anything its implementor wants.

Comment: something is declared as a @property doesn't mean it's some kind of subordinate object! That's the point confused me, I used to think a property must be a suordinate object. Thanks!